# How to Display pages with a Custom Fields in one page

Tags: custom-field, pages

I am trying to display all the pages that have custom fields of a certain value. What I would like to do is use the current page title as the value for the custom field and get all pages that have that value defined.

For example:

- Current Page is "`Surgery`".
- Custom Field Name is "`Section`".
- Custom Field Value is "`Surgery`".

I have been able to do it with post using the following code but I cant seem to work out how to do it with pages.

```
<?php woo_loop_before(); ?>

<?php
    if ( get_query_var( 'paged') ) { 
        $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ); 
    } elseif ( get_query_var( 'page') ) { 
        $paged = get_query_var( 'page' ); 
    } else { 
        $paged = 1; 
    }

    $query_args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'post', 
                        'paged' => $paged
                    );

    // Do not remove. Used to exclude categories from displaying here.
    $query_args = apply_filters( '', $query_args ); 

    remove_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'woo_exclude_categories_homepage' );

    query_posts( $query_args );
query_posts('category_name='.get_the_title().'&post_status=publish,future');    
    if ( have_posts() ) {
        $count = 0;
        while ( have_posts() ) { the_post(); $count++;

            /* Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
             * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
             * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) 
             * and that will be used instead.
             */
            get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

        } // End WHILE Loop

    } else {
?>
    <article <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.', 'woothemes' ); ?></p>
    </article><!-- /.post -->
<?php } // End IF Statement ?> 

<?php woo_loop_after(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get pages with [`get_pages()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/get_pages), in the arguments you can provide a search query for `post_meta`, like for example:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'page',
    'meta_key'   => 'section',
    'meta_query' => array( array(
        'key'     => 'section'
        'value'   => 'surgery' // here you could place get_the_title()
        'compare' => '='
    ) )
);

$pages = get_pages( $args );
```

This will return all pages (or any other post types in `post_type`) with meta_key section and meta_value surgery.

You have to alter the loop if you use this way, build your loop as follow:

```
foreach( $pages as $page ) : setup_postdata( $page );
...
endforeach; wp_reset_postdata();
```

Hope this will help you.